# Laravel Call to undefined method App\\Models\\Volunteers::sendMessage()

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am creating a page where message is sent after form is submitted. To send sms, I'm using Twilio as provider. When I try to add volunteer data,  it outputs BadMethodCallException error with following message

```
Call to undefined method App\\Models\\Volunteers::sendMessage()
```

If I remove any mentions of sendMessage() function, the function outputs the desired outcome. However the sendMessage() seems to break the code functionality.

VolunteerController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Volunteers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required',
        ]);

        $volunteerDetails = [
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
        ];

        $volunteer = Volunteers::create($volunteerDetails);

        $message = 'You have been registered as volunteer';
        $recipient = $data['phone'];
        $volunteer->sendMessage($message,$recipient);
    }

    public function sendMessage($message, $recipients)
    {
        $account_sid = getenv("TWILIO_SID");
        $auth_token = getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
        $twilio_number = getenv("TWILIO_NUMBER");
        $client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
        $client->messages->create($recipients, ['from' => $twilio_number, 'body' => $message] );
    }
```

Model Volunteer.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Volunteers extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'type',
        'district',
        'local',
        'ward_no',
        'phone',
        'email',
        'interested_area',
        'manpower'
    ];
}
```

And my route is via api

```
Route::post('/volunteer/add', [VolunteerController::class, 'store']);
```

Comment: If that is your entire Volunteers model, you’ve not defined a function called sendMessage.

Comment: Did you mean to use `$this->sendMessage` instead of `$volunteer->sendMessage`?

Comment: @brombeer yeah you were correct.

Answer (score 0):

[brombeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8034901/brombeer) solved the problem with [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73805637/laravel-call-to-undefined-method-app-models-volunteerssendmessage/73805894#comment130324175_73805637)

> Did you mean to use `$this->sendMessage` instead of `$volunteer->sendMessage`?

I used `$volunteer->sendMessage` instead of `$this->sendMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

Well to explain the issue here.

The line refers to the Model Volunteers' instance

```
 $volunteer = Volunteers::create($volunteerDetails);
```

The sendMessage($message,$recipient) method is a method of the controller class

using the $voluteer to call the sendMessage method gave the error

```
$volunteer->sendMessage($message,$recipient);
```

As suggested by @brombeer you should use "$this" rather